# SETFable vs place (CLHS) vs location (Norvig)

Tags: common-lisp, setf

Is a `setf`able the same as a *place* in CLHS and a *location* in Norvig's PAIP?

I'm trying to figure out what exactly a *place* is in Common Lisp but to me the HyperSpec's explanation

> place n. 1. a form which is suitable for use as a generalized reference. 2. the conceptual location referred to by such a place[1].

is only of limited help.

(I know it's not really the kind of question that suits SO but if someone knows a good article that explains setfable/place/location I'd appreciate a link/reference)

Comment: Have you read CLHS [5.1 Generalized Reference](http://www.lispworks.com/documentation/HyperSpec/Body/05_a.htm)?

Comment: more meta madness. we're not allowed to have the "place" tag now!

Answer (score 16):

Originally mutable data structure has a getter AND a setter. Example for `car`/`rplaca` and `cdr`/`rplacd`:

```
CL-USER 68 > (let ((a (cons 1 2)))
               (print (list (car a) (cdr a)))
               (rplaca a 'foo)
               (rplacd a 'bar)
               (print (list (car a) (cdr a)))
               (values))

(1 2) 
(FOO BAR)
```

In this example the getter are `car` and `cdr` for *cons cells*.
The setters are `rplaca` (replace car) and `rplacd` (replace cdr).

Every mutable data structure has that and usually there is no systematic way to guess the name of the setter from knowing the name of the getter.

Thus the idea was to have a registry of getter and setter. Register a setter for a getter and the user has only to know the getter. The `setf` macro (and others like `incf`, `decf` and also user defined macros) then does a lookup of the setter for the used getter.

The example above with the `setf` macro looks like this:

```
CL-USER 69 > (let ((a (cons 1 2)))
               (print (list (car a) (cdr a)))
               (setf (car a) 'foo)
               (setf (cdr a) 'bar)
               (print (list (car a) (cdr a)))
               (values))

(1 2) 
(FOO BAR)
```

As you see the use of `rplaca` and `rplacd` has been replaced by the `setf` macro.

Thus a place is basically a registered form, for which there is a setter. [defsetf](http://www.lispworks.com/documentation/HyperSpec/Body/m_defset.htm#defsetf) and [define-setf-expander](http://www.lispworks.com/documentation/HyperSpec/Body/m_defi_3.htm#define-setf-expander) are used for that.

[define-modify-macro](http://www.lispworks.com/documentation/HyperSpec/Body/m_defi_2.htm#define-modify-macro) is used to define a macro, which can modify a place.

For example we can define a way to multiply the value of a place, similar to `incf` (increment a place) and `decf` (decrement a place).

This feature is old and originally the word *field* was used instead of *place*. Thus the macros able to use a place end with *f* (field).

```
CL-USER 71 > (define-modify-macro multf (&rest args) 
               * "multiply")
MULTF

CL-USER 72 > (let ((a (cons 1 2)))
               (print (list (car a) (cdr a)))
               (multf (car a) 2)
               (multf (cdr a) 4)
               (print (list (car a) (cdr a)))
               (values))

(1 2) 
(2 8)
```